# C sizeof char* array

Tags: c, sizeof

I have a `char*` array as follows:

```
char *tbl[] = { "1", "2", "3" };
```

How do I use the `sizeof` operator to get the number of elements of the array, here 3?

The below did work, but is it correct?

```
int n = sizeof(tbl) / sizeof(tbl[0])
```

Comment: This was actually answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/c-how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array) And that was the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Not if the array was received as a parameter. Check [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10349610/481534).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Comment: @Elideb: Strictly speaking, an array can't be a parameter. A parameter defined as `char *tbl[]` is really of type `char**`; the type is adjusted at compile time.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, I know, but I still find code around with arrays as parameters, and people expect them to behave as such. I'll try to be more correct when talking about them.

Comment: @Elideb: No, you don't find C code with arrays as parameters, since that's impossible. You commonly find code with parameters defined with an array-like syntax, but those parameters really are pointers.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes,

```
size_t n = sizeof(tbl) / sizeof(tbl[0])
```

is the most typical way to do this.

Please note that using `int` for array sizes is not the best idea.

Comment: Anything wrong with using a `size_t` for sizes? Or at least something unsigned?

Comment: `#define countof(a) ((sizeof(a)/sizeof((a)[0])))` - I wonder if it is a safe way to declare such a macro. Especially for multi-dimensional arrays and such stuff...

Comment: I believe sizeof is always calculated at compile time. I can't think of a way to get a meaningful sizeof of something which is not known at compile time.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` doesn't save you a dereferencing operation. The compiler calculates size of `tbl[0]` by understanding its type, and doesn't actually generate code for it. The only thing `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(tbl[0])` would achieve for you is problem in the future if the array changes its type from `char` to something else.

Comment: @aragaer, for variable length arrays, that is not true. If you have `unsigned int n; scanf("%u", &n); int array[n];` (with added error checking), then `sizeof(array)` is calculated at run-time.

Comment: @Shahbaz I believe once compiler sees `sizeof` being called for a variable size array, it might optimize it to "multiply array length by element size" which will result in "almost compile time" sizeof. There is no thing called "array" in run time and thus there is nowhere to store its size.

Comment: @aragaer, it most certainly will. The actual multiplication is done at run-time and its value unknown at compile-time.

Comment: @Shahbaz but if we know at compile time that `int array[n]; length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);` we can assume that `length = n;` and avoid any computations at all.

Comment: Replacing `sizeof(tbl[0])` by `sizeof(char)` is not an optimization -- **nor is it correct**. `tbl[0]` is a `char*`, not a `char` (and `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition), so your "optimized" version simply yields the size in bytes of the array. `sizeof` is always evaluated at compile time unless the argument is a variable-length array.

Comment: @aragaer: `sizeof arr` where `arr` is a variable-length array is likely to be computed without a multiplication. The compiler can store the size in an anonymous object, so the multiplication needs to be done only when the type is defined.

Comment: @aragaer: We can't assume the length is `n` if `n` might change: `int n = 10; int array[n]; n = 20;`; modifying `n` doesn't affect the length of `array`. But that would be poor style.

Comment: @KeithThompson For personal reference, could you please elaborate on what was incorrect? `sizeof(NATIVE_TYPE)` is handled at compile time, and pointer decay does indeed cause `sizeof()` to provide differing results depending on the scope of the pointer (ie: local vs function scope).

Comment: @Dogbert: See my comment above, posted about an hour ago, starting with the word "Replacing".

Comment: I stand corrected. I didn't notice it was a `char*` array and not a `char` array. +1 on comments/answers. Cheers!

Comment: @aragaer, that's true. I was responding to your sentence that said: _I believe sizeof is always calculated at compile time._

Comment: @Shahbaz I didn't think about variable size arrays thinking it's a GCC extension. At least I've learned something today.

Comment: @aragaer, it used to be. It was standardized in C99.

Comment: error: division 'sizeof (char *) / sizeof (char)' does not compute the number of array elements [-Werror=sizeof-pointer-div]

Comment: @lilalinux That's a rather new (introduced about a year earlier) warning promoted to error.

Answer (score 19):

The shorter and, arguably, cleaner version would look as

```
sizeof tbl / sizeof *tbl
```

:)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will give you the number of elements in the array tb1.

```
int n = sizeof(tbl) / sizeof(tbl[0])
```

***Interpretation:***

**sizeof(tb1)** will gives the size of the entire array i.e, tb1 = **3 bytes**

**sizeof(tb1[0])** gives the size of the character as tb1[0] gives a character value(value at address tb1+0)  = **1 byte**

Division of those two will give you **3 elements**

Comment: `tbl` is an array of `char*`, not an array of `char`. If `sizeof (char*) == 4`, then you're dividing 12 bytes by 4 bytes, yield 3 *array elements*, not 3 bytes.

Comment: sorry its a typoo, it should be 3 elements not bytes..:)

Comment: @tbl still isn't a character array.

Comment: No, still incorrect. `tbl` is an array of `char*`, *not* an array of `char`. The size of `tbl[0]` isn't 1 byte unless you're on a weird system with 1-byte pointers.

Comment: but sizeof tb1[0] gives us the size of the value present at address tb1[0] which must be a character right?...

Comment: It would if `tbl` were an array of `char` (`char tbl[]`). `tbl` is an array of `char*` (`char *tbl[]`). If a `char*` (a pointer) is 4 bytes, then the whole array is 12 bytes, not 3.

Comment: This really needs fixing, because it's wrong--the sizeof(tb1) is most typically going to be 24, and the sizeof(tb1[0]) is most typically going to be 8 (12 and 4 on 32-bit systems). This is not an array of characters, it's an array of pointers.