# Dynamically declared array sizeof

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

I red [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559925/c-sizeof-char-array) but it didn't help me much.

```
int* sum;
int size = 10;
sum = calloc(10, sizeof(int));

printf("Total length: %d", sizeof(sum)/sizeof(*sum))
```

The code returns 1 as expected.

I know that it would be easier to user the size variable.

My question is that is there a way of finding out this array correct size using sizeof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than keeping track of the size yourself (eg. the `size` variable in your example), there's no portable/standard way of getting the size of a dynamically allocated block of memory.

Comment: Ok so in I want to pass this memory block as a function parameter it is necessary to pass the array size too. There is no other way. Thanks!

Comment: @TGM : pretty much, yes. You can make it more convenient by grouping the pointer and the size in a struct (and possibly even provide several functions to access and manipulate the data).