# Calculating length of a string in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
int strlength(const char *myStr){
    //variable used for str length counter
    int strlength = 0;
    //loop through string until end is reached. Each iteration adds one to the string length
        while (myStr[strlength] != '\0'){
            putchar(myStr[strlength]);
            strlength++;
        }

    return strlength;
}
```

Why will this not work as intended? I just want to find the length of a string.

Comment: And in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: I keep getting an off by one error. I.E. hello returns 6

Comment: Duplicate of [C size char* array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559925/c-sizeof-char-array)

Comment: What's the calling code to this?

Comment: If you're getting 6 instead of 5, you might do better printing `printf(" %d", mySte[strlength]);` so you can see exactly what's being processed.  But the code should produce 5 for "hello".  Are you sure you're testing what is written in the question?

Comment: @KyleRogers No, that's really not a dupe of that.

Comment: @Joe but if the string is hello. then myStr[5] should not allow the loop to execute right? So then the value should be correct

Comment: @DanielFischer how so? It's the same question. How do I find the size of an array.

Comment: @KyleRogers He is not trying to get the size of the array, but the lengh of his string, which is similar in MOST platforms, but not everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a comment on another answer:

> I am using fgets to read in a string. and i have checked to make sure that the string that was typed was stored correclty

In that case, there is a trailing newline stored, so your function computes

```
strlength("hello\n")
```

The code is correct, you just didn't pass it the input you believed to pass.

Comment: What do you want to avoid exactly? If you don't want a `\n` at the end of the string, just remove it. (Or, if `fgets` doesn't do what you want, don't use it.)

Comment: @Vlad If you have POSIX, you can use `getline()`. Otherwise, compute the length, and overwrite the newline [if there is one, if the input was longer than the size passed to `fgets`, there won't be one].

Comment: @David. I'm unsure I understand fgets properlyy then. Will it always store a '\n'?

Comment: @Vlad: No. It will only store a newline in the string if it reads a newline. "`fgets()` reads in at most one less than `size` characters from `stream` and stores them into the buffer pointed to
by `s`. Reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A `\0` is stored after the last character in the buffer."

Comment: @David. Well then it will always store a '\n' Unless you hit enter after the maximum length specified is reached correct?

Comment: @Vlad If there is a newline in the input stream, `fgets` will store it if there is space in the buffer (according to the size argument).

Comment: @Vlad: Consider a file that only contains the letter "A". Reading stops at end of file.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I understand. Is there a better option than fgets() if getline() is not avilable?

Comment: @Vlad Depends on what "better" means. You could also `scanf("%99s", myStr);` [assuming `myStr` has space for 100 `char`s], that will leave the newline in the input buffer and not store it. You can also write your own input function repeatedly calling `getchar()`.

Answer (score 3):

More reliable version:

```
size_t strlength(const char * myStr)
{
    return strlen(myStr);
}
```

Comment: I think this kinda defeats the purpose of the OP's function though :P. still +1 for mentioning the conventional way.

Comment: It's not homework. At all. I can easily fix it by subtracting 1 from my return. but i shouldn't need to and I dont know why

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also:-

```
int string_length(char *s)
{
   int c = 0;

   while(*(s+c))
      c++;

   return c;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the concept/concepts behind this.

Comment: Got it when the *(s+c) expression returns 0 as it encounters a null terminating character.. The loop stops! right? Incredible!

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about fgets() and removing the trailing `\n`.

```
while (myStr[strlength] != '\0'){
            putchar(myStr[strlength]);
            strlength++; //When mysStr[strlength] == \0, this line would have already incremented by 1
}
```

Quick fix:

```
return (strlength-1);//This will return correct value.
```

A more better approach:

```
int strlen(const char *s)
{
   char *str=s;
   while(*str)
   {
      str++;
   }
   return (s-str);
}
```